# Stop flex align-items from breaking overflow auto

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm using Flexboxes to create content that's centered on the page. However, if the text overflows, I'd like it to have a scrollbar using `overflow-x: auto`.

Obviously, this isn't working and I've been banging my head against my desk for a while. I have to be missing something simple here, but I can't for the life of me figure this out.

In the snippet, the first box is what I'd really like the second one to look like, except the flexbox is breaking it.

```css
.flex-container{
      height: 100%;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
    
.scrollable-content{
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="scrollable-content">
      <div style="background-color: red;width: 700px;height: 50px">I might be too wide on small screens, but you have a scrollbar if I am!</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="scrollable-content">
        <div style="background-color: red;width: 700px;height: 50px">I might be too wide on small screens, but you have a scrollbar if I am!</div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, for an element with `overflow: auto` to scroll, it needs a width (or height).

Normal block elements has a default width (100%), and will scroll by default, but flex items adjust to content and will not.

In this case, when flex direction is `column`, you need to add `max-width: 100%` (or `width: 100%`) to `scrollable-content`

```css
.flex-container{
      height: 100%;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
    
.scrollable-content{
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
    <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="scrollable-content">
        <div style="background-color: red;width: 300px;height: 50px">I'm small and centered</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="scrollable-content">
        <div style="background-color: red;width: 700px;height: 50px">I might be too wide on small screens, but you have a scrollbar if I am!</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I knew it was something simple! Thanks!